# Job Application & Interest in working with a company

Tags: career-development, job-change, training

I am actively looking for job opportunities and a career change.

I applied for a job (which I do not have enough knowledge and experience on - but would like to develop and advance in this profession, and this job opportunity would have also helped me in my studies - part-time studies).
The company conducted an interview (I told them about my current situation) and they gave me a test, which I did not pass, and after evaluating the results, they told me that I was not the chosen candidate. On the same day of this news, I received a job advert (from a job advertising company) that the same company which I have interest in, are looking for someone with the same skills, knowledge and experience that I currently have, and the same job that I currently have. Shall I reply to their email, and apply for this job, and maybe ask for an opportunity in working with them and in the meantime they can offer me training in the other profession which I would like to develop knowledge and skills in (and eventually - maybe after finishing my studies - switch to the other profession...)

How shall I proceed with this?

Comment: What have you got to lose?  Apply for the 2nd position.

Comment: Please don't ask "shall I".... That is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I received a job advert (from a job advertising company) that the same company which I have interest in, are looking for someone with the same skills, knowledge and experience that I currently have, and the same job that I currently have.

Your actual question ("shall I apply") is somewhat off-topic.  We don't tell people what they should or shouldn't do with their careers, rather we try to give good, professional advice about situations, and then you can make up your own mind about what to do with that advice.

That being said, it seems like this is a great opportunity for you.  Its in the company you were wanting to join, it's a position you have the skills and experience to perform. Maybe after a couple months or years you can begin to internally transition from this position to the one you wanted but didn't qualify for.  In the meantime, you can pick the brains of the people who are in that position, to begin learning the skills you'd need to get there.

Personally, I would absolutely apply to this new position.  There's nothing shameful about applying to a second position in the same company, if that's what you're worried about.  The fact that they didn't choose you the first time was almost certainly because there were other candidates who actually had the qualifications, and not because they had anything against you as a person.